# Failing to recognize an internal module when written in a referenced file

Tags: module, typescript

Typescript newbie, first project. I carefully read the handbook, but fail to solve a simple problem. I have an internal module :

```
module MDVault1Encoding {
    export function encode(store:Store, pwHash: Buffer): string {
        (...)
        return (...);
    }

    export function decode(encoded:string, pwHash: Buffer): Store {
        (...)
        return (...);
    } 
}
```

Then I have client code outside this module that calls these functions, like in an instance method :

```
this.store = MDVault1Encoding.decode(container.data, this.pwHash);
```

When the module definition and the client code live in the same `.ts` file, all goes well.

But when I put the module into an `md_vault_1_encoding.ts` file, and the client code in `fileio.ts`, adding a `/// <reference path="./md_vault_1_encoding.ts" />` in the latter's header, things go wrong.

`md_vault_1_encoding.ts` compiles neatly, but `fileio.ts` yields this :

```
$ tsc fileio.ts
fileio.ts(39,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MDVault1Encoding'.
fileio.ts(48,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MDVault1Encoding'.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere else in `md_vault_1_encoding.ts` you have a top-level `import` or `export` declaration.

This turns your file into a *module* (AKA "external module") and means your file doesn't put any properties in the global namespace.

You can either remove that `import` / `export` declaration (probably not possible), or you can add an `export` modifier to your namespace (`export module MDVault1Encoding { ...`) and then in `fileio.ts` write

```
import { MDVault1Encoding } from './md_vault_1_encoding';
```

Comment: That was it indeed, and external import in `md_vault_1_encoding.ts`. Thank you. So the rule here would be : any external import inside a file turns any modules it declares into external modules, is that it ?